# Cannot position image rollovers on page

Tags: html, css, image, position, rollovers

I'm new to HTML/CSS and am in the process of learning it in hopes of transferring the knowledge to running an online newspaper that I am the editor of. Currently, I am working on my own website which has an image rollover on it. I have run into the issue where the rollover works perfectly, but I cannot move it left or right or up and down. For each new rollover I add, they will just stack one underneath the other all the way down the page. How do i solve this issue and be able to position the rollover around the page as if it were a normal picture. Below it the code. Thanks in advance.

if you notice any other discrepancies that i need to fix, I would gladly appreciate it.

the body

```
    <div id="Chasity"> 
    <a href="http://falserealityfilmsabout.tumblr.com/IIASVoiceofChasity"><img src="http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d141/truevintage101/About%20us/72846ed1-9028-44bd-8671-3b4d7c6f7854_zps5a4e0faf.png"onmouseover="this.src='http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d141/truevintage101/About%20us/Chasitytitle2_zps8b7679b9.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d141/truevintage101/About%20us/72846ed1-9028-44bd-8671-3b4d7c6f7854_zps5a4e0faf.png'" /></a>
```

and css

```
body {
      {block:IfNotDarkLayout}
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
        color: #333;
            color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
      {/block:IfNotDarkLayout}
      {block:IfDarkLayout}
        color: #fcfcfc;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
      {/block:IfDarkLayout}
        background: {color:Content Background};
        font-family: "Century Schoolbook", Century, Georgia, serif;
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px {color:Content Background};
    }


.Chasity{
  left:300px;
  top:400px;
  position:fixed;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-right:50px;
```

{CustomCSS}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use the div:hover selector to change the image and then you can move it wherever you want, see my example here

html:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
    <div class="box"></div>
</a>
```

css:

```
a{
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    margin:auto;
}
.box{
    background:url('http://placekitten.com/200/500');
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
}
.box:hover{
    background:url('http://placekitten.com/200/501');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KLxUy/